# Do Denominator Vectors Determine the Cluster Variable

Tags: cluster-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Given a cluster algebra $A=A(\mathbf{x},Q)$, the Laurent Phenomenon states that all the cluster variables of $A$ are Laurent polynomials in the elements of $\mathbf{x}$.  Thus, any cluster variable $y$ can be written $$y=\frac{p(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{x_1^{d_1}\cdots x_n^{d_n}}$$ where $p$ is a polynomial and $d_i$ are positive integers.  We call $d(y):=(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ the denominator vector of $y$.

If $Q$ is mutation equivalent to a simply laced Dynkin diagram, all cluster variables are uniquely determined by their denominator vector.  I would like to know to what extent this holds in general.  That is:

Is it true that for any cluster algebra, the clusters are determined by their denominator vectors?  If not, what classes of cluster algebras have this property?  I am particularly interested in surface cluster algebras.

Answer (score 3):

For acyclic initial seeds, this is now Corollary 8 of Rupel and Stella arXiv:1712.08478 .

Comment: arXiv link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.08478

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is conjectured to be true in general.

As for cluster algebras from surfaces, maybe the answer lies in http://math.berkeley.edu/~williams/papers/MSW-July24v5.pdf ?

Comment: The reference for the conjecture is Conjecture 7.6 of Cluster Algebras IV by Fomin and Zelevinsky.

Answer (score 2):

For acyclic cluster algebras, a theorem like that can be found in "Buan, Marsh, Reiten: Denominators of cluster variables, J. London Math. Soc. 2009", Theorem 1.3 [(preprint)](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~marsh/research_articles/pp27.pdf).

Comment: I'm having trouble finding this statement in the Buan, Marsh, Reiten paper.  If it's there, there must be some translation required, and they don't state that they proved Fomin and Zelevinsky's conjecture, which it seems like they would have.  But maybe I'm just missing it.